# folder accessibility in document library in office365

Tags: security, office365

Is it possible to hide folders from users in O365?

User A - logs on and sees Folder A

User B - Logs on and sees Folder B but not Folder A

Answer (score 0):

This is basic SharePoint.  If User B doesn't have access to Folder A it is security trimmed from interface.

A better approach is to let users store that data in OneDrive for business. If it must be in a site look to separate libraries instead of folders. Breaking inheritance at the item level (folders are items) is a bad practice and leads to issues in maintainability down the road.